# Add a custom event type to Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I would like to develop an application that would allow my company employee to schedule their holidays from Google Calendar.

The idea would be the following:

1. The employee create an event corresponding to the holidays
2. The employee specify somewhat that this event is a holiday
3. The application send an email to the manager for validation
4. If the manager validate, the event is confirmed in the employee calendar and available for his teammate

Any idea how to specify that this event is a holiday (step 2)?

I tried to look how to add a custom event type without success.

Answer (score 1):

Do your company uses gapps for business?

As a domain admin, you can create "resources" apart from individuals calendar and share it with the whole company.

Maybe the link below might help you:

https://robinpowered.com/blog/how-to-set-up-room-resource-calendars-in-google-apps/

Comment: Not yet but we plan to. I'll check it out! The only thing with ressource that could matter if that if they don't allow conflict, it will be a problem: several person can take vacation at the same time (at least in my company ;-) )!

Comment: I undersand, Martin.

I can be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you can configure if you allow (or not) "conflicts" on the resources. ;)